# Squash a Git Merge but Retain Authorship?

Tags: git, git-squash

Is it possible to squash a merge but retain the authorship for use with git-blame?

Comment: Squashing takes multiple commits and maps them to a single commit, so not sure how one would preserve authorship, since there could be many authors.

Comment: @DavidDeutsch: That's the issue I'm running into in a nutshell. I'm breaking a folder from a 2 year old project into it's own addon so I don't want to get blamed for all the code in there (it's convenient to see who wrote what) but retaining the entire history is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: What is cumbersome about retaining the entire history? That's exactly the sort of thing that Git was designed to be good at.

Comment: The best you could possibly hope for is for git-blame(1) to respect the `co-authored-by` trailer so that all authors get blamed for that same commit. (This does not seem to be the case.) But there is no way for the blame-information for each commit to propagate since you have destroyed/discarded that metadata.

Comment: You could commit the squash commit as author `Don’t Blame Me <>`.